# How does MongoDB handle arrays when passed into sort

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, nosql

This code is sorting by different fields within the document and some of those fields are arrays of objects with the key I want to sort by. I don't understand the behavior that I am seeing when I run the following queries. I don't have a lot of experience with mongodb and didn't write these queries.

```
const dbCursor = connection.collection('container').find({});
cursor.sort({ "titles.title": 1 });
// These don't happen one after the other as shown here. It's either or.
cursor.sort({ "dates.start": 1 });
```

Titles and dates are both arrays of objects containing the key passed. Dates appears to be sorting by start date even though there may be multiple object with the the key start in it. Title is not sorting alphabetically and appears to be very random. I don't understand what is actually happening when this type of sort is performed in MongoDB.

1. How is Mongodb handling the array?
2. Is it only checking the first element in the array?
3. Is it checking all the elements in the array?
4. Is there a better way to perform this type of sorting when dealing with arrays? 

   `// one
   { "titles": [{ "title": "Zippy Mississippi Race" }, { "title": "Wacky 
   Races"}] }
   // two
   { "titles": [{ "title": "New Looney Tunes" }, { "title": "Your Bunny 
    or Your Life/Misjudgment Day" }] }
   // three
   { "titles": [{ "title": "Why Oh Why Wyoming" }, { "title": "Wacky Races" }] }`
   Returns in this order

Update:
So I have discovered that its sorts all the elements in the array. I just don't understand how it determines who the winner is. Can anyone explain why this order is correct based on sorting all the elements in the array?

Comment: Could you provide an example where the titles array is not sorting as expected?

Comment: Adam I can, but is this supposed to sort the array. The goal is to sort the documents by the title.

Comment: `cursor.sort({ "titles.title": 1 })` will sort the documents in the cursor by the 'titles.title' value; it will not sort the contents of the array. Not sure about some of the nuances of how this will behave.

Comment: Will is look at every element in the array or just the first?

Comment: Added some data, it appears that it orders the documents by the last element in the array

Comment: But the next result is out of order.

Comment: It looks like MongoDB 3.6 more clearly defines expected behavior in regards to sorting array fields (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/#array-sort-behavior). The link also gives an explanation of expected sort behavior when sorting array fields.